# No package transfer from host to guest on KVM

Tags: linux, networking, kvm-virtualization, linux-networking, libvirt

I want to assign external static IPs to my KVM guests. I do not prefer a NAT solution. What should be the configuration of network and routing tables?

[image: KVM Problem]

I manually assing a static IP to guest. I can send ICMP packages from guest to host and gateway. I can send icmp packages from gateway to guest directly. But i cannot send icmp packages from host to guest.

Comment: Are the static IPs assigned to the guests in the same network as the host and gateway?  It seems like you would need to assign a route and interface using the `route add ...` command to add a route to the guests, it will be important to make sure that you specify the gateway and interface when adding the route to use the `br0` interface, otherwise the default gateway interface(eth0) will probably be used when trying to reach the guests.

Comment: route add IP-ADDRESS br0 works. But at vm creation phase it should works with dynamic IPs. Another word broadcast packages should reach to guests.

Comment: If you know the range of dynamic IP addresses that are going to be assigned to new guests you can use `route add -net` with the appropriate mask, gateway, interface, etc you can add a route to the entire network.

Comment: Before dhcp offer and discover guests have no IP. So main problem is layer2 level transfer needed. ARP and ethernet packets don't reach the guests.